# How to fix my code for copying the cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a vba script to copy the values in the first column of sheet2 100 times to a first column on sheet1

I have some code, but it throws Run-time error 1004 to me, so can't figure out where the mistake is.

For now I have made the code to copy the values on the sheet2 to first empty row in first column in sheet1, but it doesn't work.

For example, I have on the Sheet2

```
Ara
Cl
RT
```

And the function will return to me on the list 1

```
Ara
.
.
.
Ara (X times for each element)
```

---

```
Public Sub Data()
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngcells As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long


    Set rngcells = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlUp))
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngcells

                For i = 1 To 100

                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i + lastrow, 1)) = rngSinglecell.Value


                Next
    Next
End Sub
```

> Run-time error 1004

thank you very much for help!

Comment: Where are you setting the value for `rngQuantitycells`?

Comment: It was a mistake in code, corrected it

Comment: try `Set rngcells = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlUp))`And `lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. You always need to specify the Sheet, the Range-Object is referred to.

Comment: M. Getrost, I have tried it, but still gives an error :(

Comment: @Alexey Also in the innermost `For-Loop` you are missing the Sheet-Referenz on `Cells`

Comment: I have corrected this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

- While pasting you are Passing `Cells` without any reference to sheets that could cause this error.
- Use of `xlUp` should be `xlDown`
- Lastrow should be Recalculated in Iteration or 100 Should be added to it.

**Try:**

```
Public Sub Data()

    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngcells As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim cel As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngcells = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    End With


    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For Each cel In rngcells
        .Range(.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1), .Cells(lastrow + 100, 1)) = cel.Value
        lastrow = lastrow + 100

    Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer, but your code throws the same error as well. (1004, run time error)

Comment: @Alexey... Try now .. I think I found the Problem. Corrected :)

Comment: It doesnt' give a line, sadly, it gives 1004, run time error. Let me relaunch excel and try again.

Comment: No... Try the edited Code. Recopy it and then try @Alexey

Comment: Can you please explain a little, why do you use rngcells End(xlDown) and not up?  And any idea why my code fails? As I am trying to learn a little, it would be mega useful!

Comment: Yes .. It is because you want to select the Range from `A1` to the last cell consecutively in down direction. Up would take the range up, and there is nothing up.

Comment: Maybe you can recommend some book or online cours to get more into vba?

Comment: There is a book by name `VBA for Dummies` , you can try that book